# How to render an image passed to Razor view from controller's action method as a File?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, charts, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have a controller action method which returns a file which contains an image with a chart:

```
public ActionResult EfficiencyChart(string id) {
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
    .AddTitle("Chart Title")
    .AddSeries(
        name: "Employee",
        xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
        yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
    .Write();

    myChart.Save("~/Content/chart", "jpeg");
    // Return the contents of the Stream to the client
    return base.File("~/Content/chart", "jpeg");        
}
```

How can I render it in `EfficiencyChart.cshtml`?

Answer (score 2):

In your Efficiency.cshtml, Use simple image tag with `Url.Action()` -

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName",new { id = PassYourIDHere  })" />
```

Comment: Shouldn't I use any model?

Comment: I didn't get your comment, can you please elaborate?

Comment: I am returning an `ActionEvent`(a File). Will that `ActionEvent`be passed to the View as a model?  PS: It worked.

Comment: In the EfficiencyChart.cshtml, which ever model you are using, have it include a property call Id, and then pass that as an argument in the Url.Action()